# How to mock a static function with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

How can I spy on the focus() and select() functions within Jasmine (Unit testing)?

My function:

```js
   static nextFieldOnAlt(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 18) {
            const focusableFields = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea'));
            const indexFocus = (focusableFields.indexOf(document.activeElement) + 1) % focusableFields.length;
            const input = focusableFields[indexFocus];

            input.focus();
            input.select();
        }
    }
```

The unit test:

```js
    describe('nextFieldOnAlt function', function() {
        it('check', function() {
            const event = {
                type: 'keypress',
                keyCode: 18
            };
            const focusableFields = angular.element(['<input type="number">22</input>', '<textarea>Test</textarea>']);
            spyOn(document, 'querySelectorAll').and.returnValue(focusableFields);

            Utilities.nextFieldOnAlt(event);

            expect(event.keyCode).toEqual(13);
        });
    });
```

I get the error

> focus is not a function

Tried to add spy like the `querySelectorAll`, but that didn't work.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit, but this looks wrong to me:

```
const focusableFields = angular.element(['<input type="number">22</input>', '<textarea>Test</textarea>']);
```

I think you want an array of Angular elements, so I suspect if you change it to this:

```
const focusableFields = [angular.element('<input type="number">22</input>'), angular.element('<textarea>Test</textarea>')]);
```

Then, I suspect this code will return a proper array of Angular elements, and this code in your component will return valid objects with a focus field:

```
const focusableFields = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea'));
```

I would strongly recommend stepping through code with a debugger to help address what is occuring.